# ember.js: use input range in Sortable list

Tags: html, ember.js, rubaxa-sortable

I would like to put an **input range html5** element within a **Sortable**

When I test the **Sortable** by itself the elements are sortable, the onEnd event handler is called *without problem*.

When I test the **input range** by itself the value change is registered and the event handler is called *without problem* upon change.

The problem is that the **input range** does not work anymore (I mean the handle doesn't move anymore) when combining the **Sortable** and the **input range** together.

I've tried to filter the input range using **filter option** in **Sortable** without success.

I would be glad is someone could help me on this.

*Here is my setup:*

> Ember      : 1.10.0
>
> Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.16
>
> jQuery     : 1.11.2
>
> Sortable : 1.1.1 (https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable)

*Here is my Handlebar template:*

```
<ul {{bind-attr class=":dropdown-menu :map-layers-dropdown"}} id="map-layers-sortable">
  {{#each layer in tileLayers itemController="mtgLayer"}}
      <li {{bind-attr id=layer.identifier}}>
          <section>{{input type="checkbox" checked=layer.visible}}
            <span>{{layer.title}}</span>
            {{input class="mtg-layers-draggable range" type="range" name="range" min="0" max="100" value=layer.opacity}}
          </section>
      </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

*Here is my Sortable configuration:*

```
this.sortable = Sortable.create($("#map-layers-sortable")[0], {
  group: {name: "group", pull: false, put: false},  // or { name: "...", pull: [true, false, clone], put: [true, false, array] }
  sort: true,  // sorting inside list
  disabled: false, // Disables the sortable if set to true.
  animation: 150,  // ms, animation speed moving items when sorting, `0` — without animation
  filter: ".mtg-layers-draggable",  // ".ignore-elements" Selectors that do not lead to dragging (String or Function)
  ghostClass: ".sortable-ghost",  // Class name for the drop placeholder

  scroll: true, // or HTMLElement
  scrollSensitivity: 30, // px, how near the mouse must be to an edge to start scrolling.
  scrollSpeed: 10, // px

  // dragging ended
  onEnd: function (/**Event*/evt) {
    evt.oldIndex;  // element's old index within parent
    evt.newIndex;  // element's new index within parent
    // My Code after Sorting
  });
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I've found a fix but that involves modiying the Sortable library.

I removed the evt.preventDefault(); call line 306. That was blocking event propagation to the input range

> Sortable.js
>
> 306 -                 evt.preventDefault();